# React onChange event for child component dropdown to update state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to learn how to implement a React form after converting my Vanilla JS code to React. I have an onChange that will update the parent component's (form) state as shown below. I made a child component (library) that has its own onChange event when the user selects a different document as shown below, which affects another child component it has (documents). Is there a way for me to be able to update the form state with the library ID that's selected in the library component?

```
class FormTemplate extends Component {
  state = {
    libraryId: "",
    libraryName: "",
    email: ""
  };

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Form>
        <Row>
          <Col xs={6} md={6}>
            <Form.Group controlId="exampleForm.ControlInput1">
              <Form.Label>First Signer Email</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                type="email"
                name="email"
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                placeholder="name@example.com"
              />
            </Form.Group>
            <button type="submit">POST</button>
          </Col>
          <Col xs={6} md={6}>
            <GetLibrary/>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Form>
    );
  }
}

export default FormTemplate;
```

Child library template

```
export class GetLibrary extends Component {
  state = {
    library: [],
    libraryId: ""
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    API.get("library")
      .then(res => {
        const library = res.data.library;
        this.setState({ library });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }

  handleChange = e => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    this.setState({
      libraryId: e.target.value
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { library, libraryId } = this.state;
    let document;

    if (libId !== "") {
      document = (
        <p>
          <GetDocument key={libId.toString()} libraryId={libraryId} />
        </p>
      );
    } else {
      document = <p>Choose a document</p>;
    }

    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Form.Group controlId={libraryId}>
          <Form.Label>Select Library Document</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control as="select" onChange={this.handleChange}>
            {library.map(libdoc => (
              <option key={libdoc.id.toString()} value={libdoc.id}>
                {libdoc.name}
              </option>
            ))}
          </Form.Control>
          {document}
        </Form.Group>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default GetLibraryDocument;
```

I'm essentially trying to get the libdoc.id and libdoc.name from the child component to be able to update the parent state as libraryId and libraryName in the parent form for submission (for a post API call). Is there a way to achieve this or do I need to restructure my components, and if so, how would you restructure/organize them to be efficient?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You're describing the process of [lifting the state](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) from one component to another; there is a very thorough example found in the [official React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html).

Comment: There's also the context api which allows you to share state between components without having to pass the state or event handlers through multiple components. I.e from -> library  -> document. As this makes your code tightly coupled to component tree.

Comment: @MichaelKnight My understanding is that context is generally the preferable solution when you're working with a large component tree whereas state lifting is preferable in smaller applications like OP's as it makes the components more reusable - it's definitely worth looking into as an alternate solution though!

Comment: I agree, I think if you're only passing state down two levels then prop drilling is a reasonable approach. I just really like the context api and find it easier to understand than prop drilling. I wouldn't necessarily say it makes the component less reusable. The root component should be export in it's own context therefore they will all have their own state. Alternatively you could wrap them all in one context and have a shared state if that was desirable for you particular use case (there may be performance implications of doing so though)